# What are the sense and reference of the propositions $R \notin R$, $R \in R$, where $R=\{x \mid x \notin x\}$ in Frege's Grundgesetze?

Tags: lo.logic, ho.history-overview, mathematical-philosophy

In the paper,

- *Aldo Antonelli and Robert May*, [**Frege's new science**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1305/ndjfl/1038336844), *Notre Dame J. Form. Log.* **41** (2000), no. 3, 242–-270, [MR 1943495](http://ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1943495).

the authors give the following quote of Frege, from his paper "Über die Grundlagen der Geometrie"<sup>*</sup>:

> What I call a proposition *tout court* or a real proposition is a group of of signs that expresses a thought [has a sense—my comment]; however, whatever only has the grammatical form [i.e. being a well-formed formula—my comment] of a proposition I call a pseudo-proposition.<sup>†</sup>

Since it is well-known that $$R \notin R \Leftrightarrow R \in R$$ (this is actually true if both $R \notin R$ and $R \in R$ are false, but then this seems to contradict the Law of Excluded Middle), can one rightly attribute either a reference (since they are 'propositions', their reference must be, according to Frege, either The True, or The False) or a sense (what would that be, exactly) to "$R \notin R$" or "$R \in R$"?  And if not, are "$R \notin R$", "$R \in R$" pseudo-propositions?

Furthermore, since $$R \notin R \Leftrightarrow R \in R$$ can be derived from Basic Law V, shouldn't Basic Law V be restricted to apply only to "real propositions"?  And how might that be done in the context of the *Grundgesetze*?

---

<sup>*</sup><sub>In *Jahresbericht der Deutschen Mathematiker Vereinigung*, vol. 15 (1906), pp. 293-309, 377-403, 423-30.</sub>
<sup>†</sup><sub>English translation by E-H. W. Kluge in *Gottlob Frege, On the Foundations of Geometry and Formal Theories of Arithmetic*, Yale University Press, 1971, p.69.</sub>

Comment: Don’t you need to resolve first what are the sense and reference of $R$?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek:  Of course.   However, $R$$\notin$$R$ and $R$$\in$$R$ are both propositions, and according to Frege (at least according to my understanding of Frege), propositions have only The True or The False as references.  So what would you say the sense of {x|x$\notin$x} is?

Comment: You confused Excluded middle ($P \lor \lnot P$) with Law of non-contradiction ($\lnot (P \land \lnot P)$).

Comment: @AndrejBauer:  $p$$\lor$$q$ $\equiv$ $\lnot$($\lnot$$p$ $\land$$\lnot$$q$), correct?  If so, substitute $\lnot$$p$ for $q$.  What do you get?

Comment: Excluded middle is stronger than the law of non-contradiction. The tautology you tried to write out requires the assumption of excluded middle (take $q = 0$ to derive $p = \neg \neg p$). It might not be an important distinction for your purposes, but it's a distinction worth bearing in mind in other contexts and is generally worth preserving.

Comment: By your reasoning, any two equivalent propositions could be interchanged. Since $p \lor \lnot p$ is equivalent to $\forall n, m \in \mathbb{Z} . n + m = m + n$ (because they are both true), you should agree that referring to "the law of excluded middle" is the same thing as referring to "the commutativity of addition". I think Frege wouldn't be so happy. (And by the way, this is a common misconception among mathematicians, namely that "$p$ and $q$ are equivalent" is the same as "$p$ and $q$ have the same meaning".)

Comment: @ToddTrimble:  Would you say then that:  'Law of Excluded Middle' $\vdash$ 'Law of Non-Contradiction'?  But then doesn't  $\lnot$(Law of Non-Contradiction)$\vdash$ $\lnot$(Law of Excluded Middle)?

Comment: @AndrejBauer: Regarding your second comment, I would agree with you.  How would you reformulate the 'tautology I tried to write out' so as to reflect that meaning (or "sense") must be preserved?

Comment: I don't know where you're trying to go with this. The law of non-contradiction holds whenever the connective $\wedge$ has its standard meaning (of being a meet) and $\neg p$ has the standard meaning of being the maximal (weakest) proposition whose meet with $p$ yields $0$ (false). Then non-contradiction is a tautology in intuitionistic logic. Excluded middle is not a tautology in intuitionistic logic. It might help if you consider it algebraically: Heyting algebras are to intuitionistic propositional logic as Boolean algebras are to classical propositional logic. (cont.)

Comment: An example of a Heyting algebra is a topology of open sets, where $\wedge$ and $\vee$ are given by intersection and union, and $\neg p$ (for an open $p$) is the largest open whose intersection with $p$ is empty, or in other words the interior of the set-theoretic complement of $p$. Now I'll leave it as an exercise that $p \vee \neg p$ is not generally $1$ (the whole space). Now, to answer one of your questions: we do have $p \vee q \vdash \neg(\neg p \wedge \neg q)$ and it follows that $\neg\neg(\neg p \wedge \neg q) \vdash \neg(p \vee q)$. (And therefore?)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really understand your question. I voted to close it down because it seemed terribly confused and it was not clear what you were asking. I think the person who answered you actually understood you.

Comment: @AndrejBauer:   The concept {$x$| $x$$\notin$$x$}(=$R$)  has the following sense:  _being the extension of a concept which you don't fall under_.    One can now write the senses of $R$$\notin$$R$, $R$$\in$$R$ as follows:  '_the extension of a concept which you don't fall under'  does not fall under that concept,   ' the extension of a concept which you don't fall under' falls under that concept'_.  Two questions now arise:  (i).  are these 'senses' actually coherent (if not, can they rightly be called 'senses'?), and (ii).  Can they be formed without reference to Basic Law $V$?  For (i), I

Comment: (cont.) would say 'no' to both, which means that $R$$\notin$$R$,  $R$$\in$$R$ have no senses, and therefore they are "pseudopropositions", and for (ii), there are forms of Russell's paradox which do not involve Basic Law $V$ (consider the example given in  Kevin C. Klement's paper "Does Frege have too many thoughts?  A Cantorian problem revisited" [Analysis, Vol. 65, No. 1, Jan 2005, pp. 45-9] ).  I asked my question in order to check if my analysis was correct.

Comment: As I said, I am not familiar enough with Frege to be able to participate. I can offer a logician's view: there is no mystery and everything in sight is well defined and has a meaning. The exact statement we're dealing with is expressible in first-order logic and set theory. I.e., it has the form: $\forall R . (\forall x . x \in R \Leftrightarrow x \not\in x) \Rightarrow (R \in R \Leftrightarrow R \not\in R)$. This is just ordinary logic and set theory. We can even rephrase it without set theory, as follows:

Comment: Let $R$ be a one-place predicate and $E$ a two-place relation (we secretly think of $R$ as Russell's paradoxical set and $E$ as the elementhood relation). Then we can get rid of set theory like this: $(\forall x . R(x) \Leftrightarrow \lnot E(x, x)) \Rightarrow \lnot \exists r . \forall y . R(y) \Leftrightarrow E(y,r)$. This is provable in first-order intuitionistic logic. It says: "if $R$ is the property of not being in $E$-relation with itself, then there is no individual $r$ such that the (extension of) predicate "is in $E$-relation with $r$" coincides with $R$.

Comment: @AndrejBauer:  I really like the intuitionistic analysis you gave in the above comment.   For what it's worth, I think that intuitionist logic is a better tool for the analysis of concepts (if that is one of the purposes of logic, of course) than classical logic.   I wonder if one can prove Hume's Principle in intuitionistic logic (first or second-order) ?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin: I don't think there's anything particular about intuitionism here, it just so happens that the statement goes through without excluded middle (most things are like that anyway). It's really a *logical* analysis of self-reference in Russell's class. And by the way, I saw it somewhere, it's not "my" analysis. I can't remember where, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Frege's Theorem: First Derivation of the Contradiction](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege-theorem/#2.5) for reference.

Let "$P$" abbreviate the name for the concept *being the extension of a concept which you don't fall under*:

> $[λx ∃F(x = εF \land ¬Fx)]$.

In *Grundgesetze*'s logic it is proved that $εP$ exists, where for each value of the variable $F$, $εF$ denotes the *extension* of $F$.

Now supposing $P(εP)$, by Basic Law V, we have  $¬P(εP)$, contrary to hypothesis.

Thus, from $(\varphi \to \lnot \varphi) \to \lnot \varphi$, we have: $\lnot P(εP)$. But then we have that $P(εP)$, again contrary to hypothesis.

Having derived a contradiction (which is a purely syntactical fact), we have to reject (as done by Frege) Basic Law V, i.e. to conclude with $\vdash \lnot \text { Basic Law V}$.

This means that, using Frege's "horizontal" fucntion $-$:

> $- \Delta =$ the True if $\Delta$ is the True; the False otherwise,

we have that:

> $- \text { Basic Law V}$ denotes the False.

See [Frege's letter to Russell (1902)](https://books.google.it/books?id=v4tBTBlU05sC&pg=PA127) on the contradiction:

> Your discovery of the contradiction caused me the greatest surprise and, I would almost say, consternation, since it has shaken the basis on which I intended to build arithmetic. It seems, then, that transforming the generalization of an equality into an equality of courses-of-values is not always permitted, that my Rule V is false, and that my explanations are *not sufficient to ensure that my combinations of signs have a meaning in all cases* [emphasis added].

This can be interpreted as meaning that it is not true in general that:

> for each value of the variable $F$, the *extension* of $F$: $εF$, exists.

And this in turn implies that the "combinations of signs" $εF$ is not always meaningful.

But note also Frege's clarification of the "form" of the contradiction in *Grundgesetze*'s system:

> Incidentally, it seems to me that the expression "a predicate is predicated of itself" is not exact. A predicate is as a rule a first-level function, and this function requires an object as argument and cannot have itself as argument (subject). Therefore I would prefer to say "a notion is predicated of its own extension". If the function $\Phi(\xi)$ is a concept, I denote its extension (or the corresponding class) by "$ἐ \Phi(ε)$". In "$\Phi(ἐ \Phi(ε))$" we then have a case in which the concept $\Phi(\xi)$ is predicated of its own extension.

---

See [On Sense and Reference](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege/#FreTheSenDen) (1892) :

> [page 32] Is it possible that a sentence as a whole has only a sense, but no meaning? At any rate, one might expect that such sentences occur, just as there are parts of sentences having sense but no meaning. And sentences which contain proper names without meaning will be of this kind.
>
> [page 41] This arises from an imperfection of language, from which even the symbolic language of mathematical analysis is not altogether free; even there combinations of symbols can occur that seem to mean something but (at least so far) do not mean anything, e.g. divergent infinite series.
> [...] A logically perfect language (*Begriffsschrift*) should satisfy the conditions, that every expression grammatically well constructed as a proper name out of signs already introduced shall in fact designate an object, and that no new sign shall be introduced as a proper name without being secured a
> meaning. The logic books contain warnings against logical mistakes
> arising from the ambiguity of expressions. I regard as no less pertinent
> a warning against apparent proper names without any meaning.

So, if the set $R$ does not exist, the name for it lacks reference, and thus any sentence containing it lacks truth-value.

But in a logically perfect language every expression grammatically well constructed must have reference: an object for a *name* and a truth-value for a sentence.

Conclusion: R \notin R$ is not "an expression grammatically well constructed" in Frege's system.

---

Frege's first (and unsuccessful) attempt to salvage his system was precisely to restric the application of Basic Law V (which does not apply to propositions, but to functions: $ἐf(ε) = ἀg(α) ≡ ∀x[f(x) = g(x)]$ ); see:

- W.V.Quine, [On Frege's Way Out](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2251464?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), *Mind*, Vol.64, No.254 (1955), pp.145-159.

It may be interesting to consider that, in his "modified" system sketched into the Appendix to *GG II*, Frege claims to have proved, with its modification to BL V, that:

> $\vdash \lnot x \text ^ x$

which amounts (approximately) to: $\vdash R \notin R$.

---

---

Regarding Klement's paper, it discuss a very subtle point, which supports your previous concern that Basic Law V is (presumably) not the only source of trouble in Frege's system.

As Klement notes:

> A few months after reporting Russell’s paradox, Russell despaired in a letter to Frege that "from Cantor’s proposition that any class contains more subclasses than objects we can elicit constantly new contradictions", and reports on his discovery of a Cantorian paradox regarding propositions, suggesting that, mutatis mutandis, this should be a worry for Frege’s theory of thoughts. In the
> ensuing correspondence, Russell formulates the paradox in terms of both
> generating a distinct proposition for every class, as well as generating a
> distinct proposition for every propositional function. Frege never quite
> fully appreciated Russell’s point, but nevertheless Russell had put his
> finger on a genuine issue Frege should have been concerned with, as I have
> argued elsewhere.

If we apply modern semantics to Frege's system, we have that every concept "identify" a subset of the universe. Thus, by Cantor's theorem, there are more concepts than objects in the universe.

But in Frege's system - and this assumption is prior to Basic Law V - for every concept must exists its *extension*, and extensions are objects; thus, we have already an inconsistency, as suggested by Russell.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Are you aware that for restricted classes of wff's, Basic law $V$ is consistent with second-order logic?  This leads me to believe that what engenders Russell's paradox is his "explanations", and not Basic law $V$.  Regarding Basic Law $V$ as  Frege conceived it  (that is, for functions) , one could substitute a proposition for $x$ in "$V$", provided f($p$)={ The True, The False}.  If one substituted $R$$\notin$$R$ or $R$$\in$$R$ for $x$ in Basic Law  $V$, what would be the truth-value of Basic Law $V$?

Comment: I would gladly accept your answer if you would discuss (in short form, of course) Kevin Klement's example in his paper "Does Frege have too many thoughts.  A Cantorian problem revisited" (the cite is in my latest comment to Andrej Bauer).

Comment: Since for $\epsilon$$P$, one has $\lnot$$P$($\epsilon$$P$)  $\Leftrightarrow$ $P$($\epsilon$$P$), one can form the following subset of $R$(={$x$|$x$$\notin$$x$}):  {$R$|$R$$\notin$$R$}.  Though a well-formed formula in set theory, can it be said to have a coherent "sense" as Frege understood the term?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following passage from Frege's lecture "Funktion und Begriff" (English translation by Peter Geach with the title "Function and Concept" [Note:  this is the lecture which introduced the notions "value-range" and "Basic Law $V$"]):

> It seems to be demanded by scientific rigour that we ensure that an expression never becomes *bedeutungslos*; we must see to it that we never perform calculations with empty signs in the belief that we are dealing with objects.  People have in the past carried out invalid procedures with divergent infinite series.  It is thus necessary to lay down rules from which it follows, e.g., what
>
> $\oplus$+1
>
> stands for [*bedeut*], if '$\oplus$' stands for [*bedeut*] the sun [not Frege's sun-symbol, but an inadvertent sun-symbol nonetheless--my comment].  What rules we lay down is a matter of | indifference; but it is it is essential that we should do so --that '*a*+*b*' should always have a *Bedeutung*, whatever signs for definite objects may be inserted in place of '*a*' and '*b*'.   This involves the requirement that as regards concepts, that, for any argument they should have a truth-value as their value; that it shall be determinate, for any object, whether it falls under the concept or not.  In other words:  as regards concepts we have a requirement of sharp delimitation; if this were not satisfied it would be impossible to set forth logical laws about them.  For any argument *x* for which  '*x*+1' were *bedeutungslos*, the function *x*+1=10 would likewise have no value, and thus no truth-value either, so that the concept:
>
> 'what gives the result 10 when increased by 1'
>
> would have no sharp boundries.  The requirement of sharp delimitation of concepts thus carries along with it this requirement for functions in general that they must have a value for every argument.

Note what this passage does *not* say (if Geach's translation correctly captures the sense of Frege's German).  It does not say that every wff has a *bedeutung*; rather, it says that one should restrict one's attention only to those wffs that have a *bedeutung*--only these are the subject-matter of logic (for example, how could logic handle the following 'concept'

> Colorless green ideas sleep furiously

).

With this in mind, let me consider Mauro Allegranza's example (actually Zalta's and Russell's):

> $\lambda$$x$$\exists$$X$($x$=$\hat {\epsilon}$$X$ $\land$ $\lnot$$X$($x$)), where $X$ is a second-order variable.

Of this, Russell says, in his letter to Frege:

> Therefore we must conclude that $w$ [i.e. $\lambda$$x$$\exists$$X$($x$=$\hat {\epsilon}$$X$ $\land$ $\lnot$$X$($x$)) when applied to itself in the manner Frege seems to allow--my comment] is not a predicate [concept, since at that point it has no reference or truth-value--my comment also].

It should be noted that if one takes Frege's prescription in "Function and Concept" seriously, the system in his *Grundgesetze* only applies to wffs in which variables always have references, and which only have sharp boundaries (with these restrictions, Antonelli and May show in their paper "Frege's Other Program" that the system of the *Grundegesetze* is consistent).  All Russell's challenge to Frege's system amounts to is that it challenges the notion that all wffs of the *Grundgesetze* are such.  If this is the case, then the following question must be asked:

> Did Frege, in the system of the *Grundgesetze*, allow substitutions of any wff for latin letters (free variables--this comes from J$\ddot o$nne Speck's preprint "The Russell Paradox in the Theory of the *Grundgesetze* and Why Frege could not have done better" ) and why ( given the restrictions in "Function and Concept" make that system consistent)?

Comment: Comment to *bedeuting*; see *Grungesetze* (new Engl.transl.), footnote 3 to §5 (page 9), regarding the "horizontal": "Evidently, the sign "$\Delta$" must not be without reference, but it has to refer to an object. Names without reference must not occur in concept-script. The stipulation is made such that under all circumstances "$-- \Delta$" refers to something, provided only that "$\Delta$" refers to something. Otherwise $-- \xi$ would not be a concept with sharp boundaries, thus in our sense not be a concept at all. ... 1/2

Comment: ... I here use the *capital Greek letters* as if they were names referring to something, without stating their reference." 2/2

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA:  Very interesting--Thanks!  Since for Frege, a 'concept without sharp boundaries'  is,  in his "sense", "not a concept at all", what forbids him to state this to Russell as a rejoinder to Russell's claim of an inconsistency in the  _Grundegesetze_?

Comment: For a (very) different point of view on the "correct" way to read Frege's logical symbolism, see: Gregory Landini, [Frege's Notations: What They Are and How They Mean](https://books.google.it/books?id=kDZQvy6-9rwC&printsec=frontcover) (2012) (but I've haven't read it yet).

Comment: Regarding your last comment, I think that your suggested "way out" from the paradox is not viable by the fact that (Frege's symbolic equivalent) of Russell's "contradictory" property is a well-formed formula in F's system... In Appendix to vol 2 of *Grundgesetze*, F tried to fix his system "limiting" BLV; it is interesting to note F's claim that, with this modification, he can now prove (the symbolic equivalent of): $\vdash \lnot (x \in x)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA:  though $\lambda$$x$$\exists$$X$($x$=$\epsilon$$X$ $\land$ $\lnot$$X$($x$)) is a wff of Frege' s  _Grundgesetze_,  at the point it is applied to it's 'extension'  (because of the contradiction), can it be said that it rightly has either an "extension", "sense",  or  "reference"  (its assignment to either the True or the False)?    The well- formedness of formulas is syntactical--does the grammatical sentence "Colorless green ideas sleep furiously" have an "extension", "sense", or "reference" in Frege's sense?  Consider also the cases of the aforementioned sentence

Comment: (cont.)  for which an extension _does_  exist-- those extensions that satisfy the Axiom of Foundation (the collection $V$).  Can $V$ be correctly said to be an "extension" (if so,  the contradiction follows)?  Frege, in the _Grundgesetze_  (as you rightly pointed out), said (in essence) that the Russell sentence does not have "sharp boundaries" and thus in his sense, is "not a concept at all" (note that Russell said, in his letter to Frege, that the 'predicate', "to be a predicate that cannot be predicated of itself", because of the contradiction that follows when applied to itself,

Comment: (cont.) cannot be a predicate).  Note also that he states, in his letter to Frege, the source of the problem (You state (p. 17 [pg.  23 in the van Heijenoort translation of the _Begriffsschrift_--mine and Bauer-Mengelberg's comment]) that a function, too, can act as the indeterminate element.  This I formerly believed, but now this view seems doubtful because of the following contradiction.").  Frege's restriction to propositions _tout court_  is consistent, as shown by Antonelli and May's paper "Frege's Other Program"  (Notre Dame Journal of Formal Logic, Vol. 26, No 1, 2005).